# Material and Textures not showing up properly in final render

Tags: rendering, texturing, uv, shaders, error

I have made some blender things in the past but this is the first time I have ever done anything with UV mapping, textures, etc. I was able to make a new glossy material for the metal on the model and import an image to be rendered with the material. For some reason, it looks fine in all other viewports but when I render the image out there are these spots where neither the material nor the texture is applied. I have looked at multiple questions that seem similar to this but to no avail. Below I have included what it looks like in other viewports, rendered, and the nodes I have used to import the texture. I am using cycles render engine and an HDRI map for lighting. If more information is needed let me know and I can send more screenshots. Thanks!

(Ignore the defuse shader that is unused in the node editor, it was used to try and fix the problem using a method I had found earlier that didn't work)

[image: Text]

[image: Text]

[image: Text]

Comment: Looks like you have a second object in the same place as the "main" one which is hidden in the viewport. Objects hidden in the viewport will still be visible in renders.

Comment: Wow. I can't believe how simple this fix was. I have been trying to fix this for like 3 days lmao. Thanks.